# Can't verify hashed password

Tags: php, authentication, passwords

I have this php login function that doesn't seem to work with a hashed password in my database.
Where var_dump is, it return both values of the hashed password and the member id.
If I move the var_dump after the second if, it will not return anything. Any suggestions?

```
public function logIn($id, $password)
{
    $stmt = $this->link->prepare("SELECT member_id, member_first_name, member_password FROM members WHERE member_id = ? ");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    if ($stmt->execute())
    {
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            { 
            $dbMember_id = $row['member_id'];
            $dbMember_first_name = $row['member_first_name'];
            $dbpassword = $row['member_password'];
            }


            if($id == $dbMember_id)
            {
                var_dump($dbpassword);
                var_dump($dbMember_id);

                if(password_verify($password,$dbpassword))
                {

                session_start();
                $_SESSION['session_member_first_name'] = $dbMember_first_name;
                $_SESSION['session_member_id'] = $dbMember_id;
                $_SESSION['last_acted_on'] = time();
                }
            }

    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `$password` is coming from where?

Comment: it's an argument of the function

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's coming from an HTML page. where I am calling a function LogIn and passing in the function ID and Password. Before using the hash password my login worked. The code was: if ($id == $dbMember_id  && $password == $dbpassword) session_start() ...

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: What is the values that is var_dump?  and could you also perhaps include the var_dump values of $password

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't get any errors. I should mention, that I have the exact same login for admin, and it works.

Comment: @CoenieRichards The var_dump values are the entered id, that was found in the database and the long hashed password. After I move the var_dump inside the if, after password_verify(), I don't get nothing.

Comment: What is the size limit of the field member_password? Perhaps when you are saving the hashed password it gets trimmed or something.

Comment: @CoenieRichards Thanks. That was the problem. :) All working now.